# How do I print the rest of these numbers?

Tags: c++

My assignment is as follows:

> Print numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., `userNum` as shown, with each number indented by that number of spaces. For each printed line, print the leading spaces, then the number, and then a newline. Hint: Use `i` and `j` as loop variables (initialize `i` and `j` explicitly). Note: Avoid any other spaces like spaces after the printed number. Ex: `userNum = 3` prints:
>
> ```
> 0
>  1
>   2
>    3
> ```

So far I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int userNum  = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;


  for (i; i <= userNum; i++)
  {
    for (j; j <= userNum; j++)
    {
      cout << userNum << endl;
    }   
  }   

  return 0;
}
```

I'm still new to this. How do I loop in the rest of the numbers and spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Your loops are nested syntactically, but not semantically, since `j` is only initialised outside the loops. Also, you're printing `userNum` which is most definitely not what you should be printing.

Think about why two nested loops are required: one to count up from 0 to `userNum`, and another one (the inner one) to count the spaces before each of these numbers. The second has to be a loop as well, because the number of spaces depends on how far the first loop has gotten so far.

Try modifying your loops so that the loop over `i` takes care of the numbers, and the loop over `j` takes care of the spaces.

Hint: you can (and should) declare loop variables inside the first part of the `for` construct:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= userNum; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= /*something*/; ++j) {
```

Since this is obviously a learning exercise, I am intentionally not giving out a full answer.

Comment: @DieterLücking Depends on the `something`, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, or that something

Comment: @Angew, why are you doing OPs assignment (though you pretending otherwise)?  are you his servant? Your answer is wrong, since two levels of looping is not necessary. Think over how to avoid it. As well, <= should be < in your code.

Comment: @JayKumarR I am not doing the OP's assignment, what makes you say that? I am offering explanation, and a few hints. And which `<=` should be `<` according to you? The one with the unspecified right-hand side? BTW, this can of course be solved without nested loops, but they are in line with the hint in the OP's assignment.

Comment: @JayKumarR Sub-optimal is not wrong. It is merely sub-optimal. It can become wrong if further constraints are added to the problem--a runtime performance requirement that cannot be met with a slower algorithm, for example--but there are no such constraints given here.